Java Maven+Spring Project: JSP Webpage 404 Error
I've been having issues getting my JSP webpage to display on my browser when I execute my Spring Boot project.
I'm using Spring MVC to map my JSP with an application properties file and a main controller class. The controller class should return my JSP home page file when I go to localhost:8080 on my browser, but it is indicating a 404 error instead. I enabled the Spring Web debugger in application properties so I could inspect the issue, but I'm not quite sure what it is.
Here is the command line output while using the debugger:
2024-12-08T21:39:43.133-05:00  INFO 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-12-08T21:39:43.133-05:00  INFO 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-12-08T21:39:43.134-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-12-08T21:39:43.134-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-12-08T21:39:43.134-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-12-08T21:39:43.134-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@1083e6a0
2024-12-08T21:39:43.134-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@4cf507d1
2024-12-08T21:39:43.135-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-12-08T21:39:43.135-05:00  INFO 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-12-08T21:39:43.140-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2024-12-08T21:39:43.147-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to main.controller.MainController#displayMainPage(Model)
2024-12-08T21:39:43.162-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2024-12-08T21:39:43.162-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name [index], model {message=Hello, welcome to the JSP web application!}
2024-12-08T21:39:43.163-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]
2024-12-08T21:39:43.165-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp", parameters={}
2024-12-08T21:39:43.169-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-12-08T21:39:43.169-05:00  WARN 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceHandlerUtils    : "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]"
2024-12-08T21:39:43.170-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2024-12-08T21:39:43.172-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp.]
2024-12-08T21:39:43.174-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2024-12-08T21:39:43.175-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2024-12-08T21:39:43.175-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2024-12-08T21:39:43.176-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2024-12-08T21:39:43.181-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2024-12-08T21:39:43.184-05:00 DEBUG 15944 --- [calculatorApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404

Here is my project directory structure:
enter image description here
Here is my controller file:
package main.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String displayMainPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello, welcome to the JSP web application!");
        return "index"; // Maps to /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
    }
}

Here is my application.properties file:
spring.application.name=calculatorApp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

And lastly, here is my child pom.xml file in my Maven /main folder:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--The identifier of the parent POM-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>calculatorApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>calculatorAppWeb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>calculatorAppWeb</name>
    <description>Calculator Application, Controller, and View</description>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL for JSP support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Tomcat Embed for JSP support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>


TROUBLESHOOTING EFFORTS
I attempted changing the configuration to use a web.xml file instead of the application properties Spring MVC configuration. Had build issues because of this, so I went back to the Spring MVC route.
Tried moving the spring mvc, javax and tomcat dependencies to my Maven parent BOM, which changed nothing.
I was initially using the Spring MVC library to map bind my mappings in my controller class, but this was unsuccessful and I changed to using the spring framework to do this by suggestion. This route at least got tomcat to run on localhost:8080.

Any help is greatly appreciated! <3
Thank you much.

Judging from your pom why do you have a spring-webmvc dependency as you apparently are using SPring boot, that should be a spring-boot-starter-web dependency. Looks like you are building a JAR not a WAR so the WEB-INF/jsp directory won't resolve properly. THe jstl version you have is incompatble as that is for the old servlet api and not the new servlet api. Why an additional parent pom? Finally don't use JSP but rather something like Thymeleaf to write pages in the current day and age.

I switched to Thymeleaf and got it working. Thanks for the advice
